# Two times of the standard error or two times the standard error

Tags: meaning

> A contour interval corresponds to the confidence level of two times of the standard error.

In this sentence would it mean the same if I don’t use “of” before “standard error”?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the "of" would be the most commonly used.  With the "of" would be non-standard, bordering on incorrect, unless there is some context or mathematical meaning to this sentence that I am missing.

Also, while "two times" is not incorrect, "twice" is much more commonly used instead.

Comment: We normally use "twice" for something larger by a factor of two; we use '[number] times' for factors of three and greater. "In addition, for very small sample sizes, the 95% confidence interval is larger than **twice the standard error**" - [Handbook of Biological Statistics](http://www.biostathandbook.com/standarderror.html)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Good point.  Added that in

Comment: Until about 100 years ago, more or less, 'thrice' for three times was not unusual, but it is archaic now.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that reminds me of "tuppence" and "thruppence".

Comment: I daresay the commonest-used multiple terms two, and maybe three, get special words, and the larger ones, three or four plus, are left to a standard form.

Comment: In this context I would think that "of" should be replaced by "equal to".